# Array Slicing not working

Tags: python-3.x

I have defined the following function, which looks for the indices in which the values of the array rise above a certain level. Instead of looking throughout the entire array, I just want to look at a slice of it. However, when I run my program there seems to be a problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def crossingTime2(self, level, channel_data, times, min0):
    ndata = len(channel_data[min0 :min0 + int(30)])
    for i in range(ndata-1):
        thisADC = channel_data[i] 
        nextADC = channel_data[i+1]
        if thisADC >= level and nextADC < level:
            return times[i] 
    raise RuntimeError("This is a bug! Investigate!")
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Can you provide more details and/or an example, please?

Comment: When I run the code, the following message pops up:                       RuntimeError: "This is another bug! Investigate"                                                   which  is supposed to happen since that was defined in the function, but my problem is that I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: When I try to do                                                                                                 n_tries = len(channel_data[min0:])                                                                                       it seems to be working fine.

Comment: That's because the `for` ends and we hit the `raise`. This could be either because the `for` never begins or the `if` statement inside it is never `True`. Try put some trusty `print()` inside the loop. What happens? Are the variables what you expect?... It's hard to debug without some more details... What's the input?

Comment: I think you are right, after several tests I believe that the if statement is never fulfilled so the programs jumps to the RuntimeError.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major issues. The first is that you are looping `i` always from `0` to `29` (or less eventually, depending on `channel_data` length). This means that no matter what you set `min0` to, you'll always check `channel_data` values from `0` to `N`, not `min0` to `N`.

Second (possible) issue is the `if` statement. If you are looking for peaks in `channel_data` than you shouldn't have that second condition `nextADC < level`, otherwise that statement will be `True` only if `channel_data` values rise above `level`'s value **and** than drop back down again; e.g.,

```
channel_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1]
min0 = 2 # Let's consider this slice: [3,4,5,6]
level = 5
```

`slice_of_channel_data[2] >= level` indeed, but `slice_of_channel_data[2+1]` is **not** less than `level`, so this will give you a `RuntimeError`.

Is this behavior correct? It depends on what you are trying to accomplish so consider editing that if statement.

---

Code solution:

```
def crossingTime2(self, level, channel_data, times, min0):
    ndata = len(channel_data[min0 : min0 + 30]) # Slice of maximum 30 values
    for i in range(min0, min0 + ndata - 1): # Fixed range
        # Make sure this condition behaves as you expect.
        # Otherwise change it to 
        # for i in range(min0, min0 + ndata):
        #     if channel_data[i] >= level:
        #         return times[i]
        if channel_data[i] >= level and channel_data[i+1] < level:
            return times[i] 
    raise RuntimeError("This is a bug! Investigate!")
```

---

### Update

In the ligh of what *OP* said I'm editing the answer.

The goal is to find the fall and rise time of the following signal.

[image: Signal]

```
# Function crossing_time() returns a tuple of 
# 3 elements: (t_before, t_min, t_after)
# where t_before is the time before channel_data
# starts falling, t_min is the time when 
# channel_data reaches it's minimum and 
# t_after is the time after channel_data 
# has risen again.
# 
# It raises RuntimeError if doesn't find 
# t_before or t_after.
# 
# Parameters:
#     channel_data: values of the signal
#     time: time axis for channel_data
#     base_level: the base level of channel_dat;
#                 i.e., the average value of 
#                 channel_data before and after
#                 the drop.
#     tolerance: sensitivity to apply when searching
#                for t_before and t_after.
#                Set as default to 10**-3. 

def crossing_time(channel_data, time, base_level, tolerance = 10**-3):
    # Find where the minimum of the signal is:
    pos_min = channel_data.index(min(channel_data))
    # t_min is the time when the signal reaches the minimum
    t_min = time[pos_min]

    # finding the time right before the drop
    i = pos_min
    while abs(channel_data[i] - base_level) > tolerance:
        if i == 0: # Time before the drop not found => Error
            raise RuntimeError("This is a bug! Investigate!")
        i -= 1
    t_before = time[i] # time right before the signal drops

    # finding the time right after the drop
    i = pos_min
    while abs(channel_data[i] - base_level) > tolerance:
        if i == 0: # Time after the drop not found => Error
            raise RuntimeError("This is a bug! Investigate!")
        i += 1
    t_after = time[i] # time right after the signal rises

    return (t_before, t_min, t_after)
```

#### About `tolerance`

Imagine `channel_data` and `base_level`to be:

```
channel_data = [0,1,-1,0,1,-999,1,0,0,1,0]
base_level = 0.5
```

You can't use a condition like: `while channel_data[i] != base_level` because you have no warranty that `base_level` value is actually in `channel_data`.
So insetead of this we use the parameter `tolerance` so we can check if `channel_data[i]` and `base_level` are close enough to be considered equals, insetad of actually checking if they are equal.

Set `tolerance` to fit your needs. It dipends on how big/small are the values of the signal you are working with.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your suggestion. I have a signal which resembles this: https://www.i2u2.org/elab/cosmic/graphics/PMTpulse.gif . What I want to know is when the signal falls below the 90 % to 10 % level and when it rises back and how long did that take. I don't want to look through the entire array, but rather at slice of it.

Comment: And just to clarify, the 90 % level is close to where the signal is flat, and the 10 % level is where the signal is close to the minimum point.

Comment: Let's see if I understood. Let `s` be a **slice** of 30 samples of the signal. Let `max` be the maximum value of `s`. You want to know how much time the signal takes to go from `0.9*max` to `0.1*max`?

Comment: The signal looks just like what the image link shows. The goal is to find in how much time the signal went from the baseline in this case the 90 % level to the minimum 10 % level and how much it took to reach again from the 10 % level to the 90 % level. Basically, finding the fall and rise time. I hope that made more sense.

Comment: Alright. Therefore I have 2 questions. 1. Why looking to only a slice of the array? Are you, for some reason, sure the fall and rise is all in those 30 samples? 2. Are the values of the signal positive or negative when it falls?

Comment: To answer your first question, I want to look at a slice of the data because there is a large noise level before and after the signal drops. To be sure that the signal drops, I find the location of the minimum value in the array. Then I take a slice of the array which occurs before the minimum and do the same to find the time in which the signal return to the original value. The values of the signal are counts, so when the signal falls the number of counts is reduced. These signals are for photomultipliers, maybe that helps explain things.

Comment: Since you already find the index of the minimum value you could run two loops, one going forward and one going backwards to find index before and after the drop. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the iterations that do not satisfy the criteria? I have tried the code that you suggested, but the signal will not always be as nice as the example I show you.

Comment: @RamiroTorres since `crossing_time` raises `RuntimeError` on fail, you could wrap it in a `try/except` and use `pass` to ignore signals that don't satisfy the criteria.